# Strange behavior while calling UITextViewDelegate ShouldTextChangeIn

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, hashtag

I have a `UITableViewCell` where i have a comments `UITextView` to write comments. While writing down the comments i check out for `#hashtags` and `@mentions` to check their availability on the server side of the app and display them in a `tableView`.

The issue is that once the delegate method is called i cannot reset it to check in other if statements. For instance the `" "` space character *"If statement is never called if i started my text by a `#hashtag`"* so i cannot know if it is the end of a `#hashtag` or a `@mention`. And also `#hashtag` and `" "` if statements are never called if i started my text with `@mention`

The ranging and everything is working perfectly fine but when i type space it is not reseting to start a new `#hashtag` or `@mention`

Do i need to reset the `range` or what do i have to do?

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if textView == postCommentTextView {
        if textView.text == "#" {
            recordingHash = true
            recordingMention = false
            startParseHash = range.location

        } else if textView.text == "@" {
            recordingHash = false
            recordingMention = true
            startParseMention = range.location

        } else if textView.text == " " {
            recordingHash = false
            recordingMention = false
            createdHashesArray.append(createdHashString)
            createdHashString = ""
        }


        if recordingHash != nil {
            if recordingHash == true {
                var value = String()
                print("COUNT: \(textView.text.count)")
                if startParseHash <= (textView.text.count - startParseHash) {
                    let createdRange = NSMakeRange(startParseHash, textView.text.count - startParseHash)
                    value = textView.text(in: createdRange.toTextRange(textView)!)! //as! NSString
                    createdHashString = "\(value)"
                   // print("hash:\(createdHashString)")
                }
                print("hash:\(createdHashString)")
                if textView.text.count == 0 {
                    recordingHash = false
                    recordingMention = false
                   // createdHashesArray.append(createdHashString)
                    createdHashString = ""
                }
            }
        }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you check for the character you should be using text variable not `textView.text`.  `text` gives you the current character (or whole text that was pasted in) `textview.text` gives you the whole text

Comment: Yess...i will have to check the `value` of the character then and go from there.

Comment: The code really needs to be completely redone properly. Keep in mind that a user can paste in text so don't just assume one character at a time is being entered. And of course a user can delete as well. And lastly, don't forget the user can select any text and then type or paste.